# Pagination Error in Jekyll After Update to v2

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I just started to set up pagination with Jekyll. While I was following a [tutorial](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/), I recognized that message saying there was a newer version. So, I followed this and copy pasted the first example given in the [gem repository](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2) of jekyll-paginate-v2 which I found on GitHub.

Unfortunately this is not going to work, telling me that I would combine new and old pagination logic. The error is:

```
    AutoPages: Disabled/Not configured in site.config.
    Pagination: Legacy paginate configuration settings detected and will be used.
    The new jekyll-paginate-v2 and the old jekyll-paginate logic cannot both be configured in the site config at the same time. Please disable the old 'paginate:' config settings by either omitting the values or setting them to 'paginate:off'.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    .../paginationGenerator.rb:37:in `generate': The new jekyll-paginate-v2 and the old jekyll-paginate logic cannot both be configured in the site config at the same time. Please disable the old 'paginate:' config settings by either omitting the values or setting them to 'paginate:off'. (ArgumentError)
```

I omitted the file references to jekyll (none of my files was listed). Also I do not see a file called site.config (neither in my coder nor in the examples). What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: I had a look into paginationGenerator.rb and the check that creates the error message.
I figured that it may be related to lines 36-38 I copied from the first repository example. I removed these lines and deleted my cache and installed the bundle again. Now it is working. However, that's not a real solution to me because the example seems to be valid if run separately (I cloned and tested the repo). In addition the check which fails looks exactly for the option which seems to be set be these lines.

Comment: `site.config` in Jekyll is `_config.yml` you access it by using `site.key`. Also note that jekyll-paginate-v2 isn't a new version of jekyll-paginate. I understand the confusion, but they are separate repos. jekyll-paginate-v2 does its best to be compatible with jekyll-paginate configuration, but sometimes it fails. Do you have this site in a public repo? It would be much easier to help if we could see the code.